# How do I add the same sequential class to each nested div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, each

I have three divs with the class .outer and each of those divs contain 1-3 other divs with class .inner. I want the class .inner0 to be added to the .inner divs in the first .outer div, the class .inner1 to be added to the .inner divs in the second .outer div, and so on.

Here is what I have:

```
$.each($('.outer'), function(index) {
    $('.inner').addClass("inner" + index);
});
```

This adds .inner0, .inner1, and .inner2 as classes to every single .inner div on the page. What should I be doing differently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get the `.inner` that are inside the selected `.outer`. You could use `context` in second arg like below to select the `inner` inside selected `outer`,

```
$.each($('.outer'), function(index) {
    $('.inner', this).addClass("inner" + index);
    //equivalent to $(this).find('.inner').addClass('inner' + index);
});
```